# Find $ \lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{{(\log n)}^a}}{n^2}$ if $a>1.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

let $a >1$ Then $$ \large \lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{{(\log n)}^a}}{n^2}$$

equal to what.it seems to me that it goes to infinity.

i was thinking to using some inequality of $e^x$ .but got nothing . is my guess correct ? please provide some hint .

Thanks very much.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $$n^2=e^{2\log n},$$ so your ratio equals $$e^{(\log n)^a - 2\log n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $m=\log n$, so $n= e^{m}$

$$\large \lim_n \frac{e^{[(\log n)^a]}}{n^2} = \lim_m \frac{e^{(m^a)}}{e^{2m}} = \lim_m e^{m^a-2m}$$

Because $(m^{a}-2m) \rightarrow +\infty$, the limit is $+\infty$.